# Resource usage in interconnected web of objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have on hand a system of database-driven entities which very seriously use the relational aspect of the database.

Like for example, a table to describe animals.
Then a table to describe insects.
Then a table that describes relationships between animals and insects and the nature of it. This table is keyed by foreign keys from the first two tables.

In the end, I get an entity Animal that looks like this:

```cs
public class Animal {
Guid ID;
String Name;
Range<Int> mass;
Enum physique;
Enum dietType;
Enum lifestyleType;
IQUeryable<Insects> insects;
}
```

Where each Insects is like this:

```cs
public class Insects{
Guid ID;
Guid animalID;
Guid insectID;
Animal animal;
Insect insect;
Enum relationship;
}
```

Relationships can be something like “animal eats insect”, or “insect feeds on animal corpse”, or “symbiosis”, or “parasitic”, etc…

The entity Insect is as follows:

```cs
public class Insect{
Guid ID;
String name;
Enum wingType;
Enum socialStructure;
String camouflage;
IQueryable<Animals> animals;
}
```

Where each Animals is an alias for entity “Insects” we saw previously.

So when I create a new EcosystemEntities db, I can query it for… let’s say `db.Animals.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Lupus")).ToList()`

This gives me a List where each Animal contains a List, where each Insects contains an Insect, where Insect contains List, where each Animals contains an Animal, where each Animal … et cetera.

Potentially I can have any single Animal, through these links, connected to all other insects and animals in the database. When I have a single Animal variable like that, is it de-facto equivalent to loading whole `EcosystemEntities db` into memory, just more difficult to traverse? What happens to a List? Does it essentially have `EcosystemEntities db` repeated i times? Would I be better off using a single `EcosystemEntities db` and multiple `List<Guid>` by which I would use `db.Insects.Where(i => db.Relationships.Where(r => animalIDs.Contains(r.animalID)).Contains(i.ID)).Select(i => i.name).ToList();`? Should I be worried about performance when I'm using Linq in this context?

My database can describe tens of thousands of distinct entities across, say, 15 types, and the number of connections between just two **types** of entities is in hundreds of thousands or even over a million.

Comment: Not unless you're actually traversing every object.  By default EF uses lazy loading, so  you won't load other references unless you access them.  If you turn off lazy loading, then you need to .Include() the references you want loaded.

Comment: A database can be thought of as a single table with all the table columns join together into a single table.  The single table would contain a lot of nulls on rows where columns aren't needed.  When a table is broken into smaller tables these a views of the large table that reduce the amount of memory by eliminating a lot of nulls.  A list is simply a collection of rows from the flat table.  The list doesn't copy the actual data from the database but instead is just a list of pointers to the original data in the database provided you don't create a 'new' object in your linq.

Comment: Create a Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> instead of a list which minimizes the amount of data used.

Comment: Erik, Thanks a lot for your explanation. You should make it an answer. Based on it, I found this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx
It explains how to turn lazy loading on and off for certain types, in certain calls, or across the whole instance. I checked up on my entities and luckily all the cross-references are implemented through virtual interfaces.